# split the date range by every 6 months dynamically. Start date can be any thing, but add up to month range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help to split the date range by every 6 moths and the start date could be anything but using the start date we need to add up to 09-30 only and the next day which is 10/01 should become start date. I tried using recursive cte but still not getting the exact result

```
startdate  enddate
06-22-2018   09-30-2022
```

output

```
startdate  enddate
06-22-2018 09-30-2018
10-01-2018 03-31-2019
04-01-2019 09-30-2019
10-01-2019 03-31-2020
04-01-2020 09-30-2020
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select startdate, eomonth(datefromparts(year(startdate), 9, 1)) as enddate, enddate as orig_enddate
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, enddate), eomonth(dateadd(month, 5, dateadd(day, 1, enddate))) as enddate, orig_enddate
      from cte
      where enddate < orig_enddate
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a465998f2bf2e865d1962282f5536563) is a db<>fiddle.

It is unclear what year you want for the first row.  As per your question, this uses Sep 30th of the year of the startdate.

If you need more than 100 dates, then add `option max(recursion 0)`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, as a first row ins start date we have to as is and add the days up to 9/30 and then next cycle the start date would be end date + 1 (it will become 10/01)

Comment: I am getting Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.error while using the datefromparts and eomonth functions, please help

Comment: @sql2020 . . . I fixed a couple of typos and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: getting some missmatching for  1999-10-01  we are getting corresponding result as  1999-09-30. this is output for 3 columns 1999-10-01 1999-09-30 2022-12-3..like for every 1999-10-01 we are getting 1999-09-30  instead of 2000-03-31

Comment: for your question, the first row for start date should take given date(as is)

Comment: @sql2020 . . . I mention that in the answer.    Your question is not clear on what to do.  It says "but using the start date we need to add up to 09-30 only", which is why I put the end date on the first row as Sep 30th.

Comment: can you please tell me what if the date starts from 1999-10-01 and should end by 2010-04-01.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which uses an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (startdate date,  enddate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('06/22/2018','09/30/2022')

;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Grp = sum( case when day(D)=1 and month(D) in (4,10) then 1 else 0 end) over (order by d)
     From  @YourTable A
     Cross Apply (
                    Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,startdate,enddate)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),startdate) 
                        From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                  ) B
)
Select StartDate = min(D)
      ,EndDate   = max(D)
 From cte
 Group by Grp
 Order By min(D)
```

**Returns**

```
StartDate   EndDate
2018-06-22  2018-09-30
2018-10-01  2019-03-31
2019-04-01  2019-09-30
2019-10-01  2020-03-31
2020-04-01  2020-09-30
2020-10-01  2021-03-31
2021-04-01  2021-09-30
2021-10-01  2022-03-31
2022-04-01  2022-09-30
```

**Option where we JOIN to an ad-hoc calendar table (note the TOP 10000 and base date of 2000-01-01)**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,startdate date,  enddate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'06/22/2018','09/30/2022')

;with cte as (
Select A.*
      ,B.D
      ,Grp = sum( case when day(D)=1 and month(D) in (4,10) then 1 else 0 end) over (order by d)
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  (
         Select Top 10000 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),'2000-01-01') 
           From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
        ) B on D between startDate and EndDate
            and  (D in (startdate,EndDate) 
                  or ( day(D) in (1,day(eomonth(d))) and month(D) in (3,4,9,10))
                  )
 )
 Select ID
       ,StartDate = min(D)
       ,EndDate   = max(D)
 From cte
 Group by ID,Grp
 Order By ID,min(D)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate
1   2018-06-22  2018-09-30
1   2018-10-01  2019-03-31
1   2019-04-01  2019-09-30
1   2019-10-01  2020-03-31
1   2020-04-01  2020-09-30
1   2020-10-01  2021-03-31
1   2021-04-01  2021-09-30
1   2021-10-01  2022-03-31
1   2022-04-01  2022-09-30
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but when I change the dates it is not giving right result as above, basically we have fiscally year 10/01 - 09/30 and need to divide  as half to determine the half year results. please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @Ashwin Just a minor tweak to the GRP logic.  The fiscal year should really have been part of the question

Comment: @sql2020 Always happy to help

Comment: Hi john, i tried to spin with original table but its keep running forever may be coz' of cross join, my table has nearly 350k rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why a CROSS JOIN ?  That could generate a ridiculous number of records.  Perhaps a small adjustment ... rather than FROM YOURTABLE A   how about FROM ( your query here) A

Comment: sorry my bad, not cross join, its cross apply. Still the same query has been running from min's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207543/discussion-between-sql2020-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: @sql2020 350K rows is not that bad ... let me noodle this a bit.   Can't go into a CHAT right now.  I have a call at 2:30 that requires a bit of prep

Comment: sorry, unfortunately query running  forever with top 10k rows.

Comment: @sql2020 No worries.  Have a hard time understanding how a recursive CTE beats a simple join,   :)